# How to add columns and give result in separate variable

Tags: java, file

I have a text file of format

1. aaaaa     128321     123465
2. bbbbb     242343     424354
3. ccccc     784849     989434

I would like to add values in 2nd column and 3rd column into separate variables.

*I am new to Java*
Thank you.

Below is code that i used but i want the sum:

```
    File f = new File("SampleInput.txt");
    try{
            ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);       
                 for(int x =1; x < lines.size(); x++){
                       System.out.println(lines.get(x));
                 }

       }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("File not found!!!!");}
}
public static ArrayList<String> get_arraylist_from_file(File f) 
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    s = new Scanner(f);
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        list.add(s.next());
    }
    s.close();
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = lines.get(x);
String[] columns = line.split("\\s+"); // \\s+ is regex that splits string by 1 or more white-characters

String first = columns[0];
String second = columns[1];
String third = columns[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);       
        int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
        for(int x = 0 ; x < lines.size(); x += 3){
            sum1 += Integer.parseInt(lines.get(x + 1));
            sum2 += Integer.parseInt(lines.get(x + 2));
        }
        System.out.println("sum1=" + sum1 + " sum2=" + sum2);
```